# Create a list of non-overlaping segments

Tags: loops, iterator, combinations, segment

I'm new to Python and I want to find an elegant solution to this problem:
I have a set of interesting segments defined by three attributes (bottom, top, value).
I want to create all possible combinations and add the values to all combinations.The constraint is that the segments don't overlap (bottom2>top1, bottom3>top2 etc...).
So the combinations may have 1, 2, 3 or more segments.
I know how to do it in a "raw" way with multiple nested loops but I was looking to a more efficient way

Created a class that defines my segment:

```
class passe_min:
def __init__(self, num, bottom, top, value):
    self.bottom=bottom
    self.num=num
    self.top=top
    self.value=value
def __lt__(self, other):
     return self.top < other.top
```

Built a test case:

`mineralized=[0, 1, -1, -2, 3, 4, 1, 0, -1, -1, -1, 4, 3, 5, 2, -2, -1, 7, 1, -1, 2, 3, 4, -1, -1, 1, 1, 3, 4, -1]`

Created a list of instances and sorted them based on bottom value. Each segment cost a certain amount (here "-3") to built so it is a filter for my "interesting" segments. Segments are from 3 to 7 unit in length:

```
for i in range(len(mineralized)):
for j in range(3,8):
    if i+j > len(mineralized):
        pass
    else:
        val =0;
        for k in range(i,i+j):
            val+=mineralized[k]; 
        if val-3>=0:
            l+=1;
            liste.append(passe_min(l,i+1, i+j, val));
```

I can create a list of 2-segments sets:

```
for obj in liste:
bot_next_passe=obj.top+1;
while indic==0:
    for obj in liste:
        if bot_next_passe>=30:
            indic=-1;
        elif bot_next_passe<obj.bottom:
            pass
        else:
            bot_next_passe=obj.top+1;
            yolo+=1;
            print(bot_next_passe, yolo)
```

I can do the same for all type of sets (3-segments and so on) but I feel like there is a much simplier solution which I cannot find easily.
Any help is welcome and I thank you in advance. I'm not trying to pass my work to the community but any hint or path to explore is good for me!!!